# How to do a nested WHERE in Zend Framework 1 using Zend_Db_Select with AND and OR operators?

Tags: zend-framework

So... I've inherited this rather large project based on Zend Framework 1.12 and a feature that I'm trying to add involves a more complex database operation than what I'm used to doing with the project. I'm extremely new to Zend Framework, or MVC for that matter. I found an answer for Zend Framework 3 which would have been perfect but I have to make do with this version.

The function basically builds a Zend_Db_Select based on various parameters and the feature I'm trying to add will involve joining two different tables and checking if a specific combination exists in one or the other.

Here's what I have so far:

```
//SQL that I'm trying to do. Assume table1 and table2 are already joined. 
//Ignore the imperfect syntax. I'm trying to get the concept across.
//SELECT * FROM (table1 joined to table2 by a common key) 
//WHERE ( (table1.column1 = myParam1) AND (table1.column2 = myParam2) ) 
//OR WHERE ( (table2.column1 = myParam1) AND (table2.column2 = myParam2) )


public function buildSelect($params){
//Zend code starts here
//This one starts the Zend_Db_Select
$select = $this->select();
$table1Name = get_table_name_from_object($table1);

//lots of preexisting code here

//my code starts here.
$table2Name = get_table_name_from_object($table2);

$select->join($table2Name, "$table1Name.key = $table2Name.key", array('column1', 'column2', 'key');

//After I wrote this, I instantly realized why it won't work the way I intended it but putting it here to show what I tried at which point I got stuck.
$select->where("($table1Name.column1 = ?) OR ($table2Name.column1 = ?)",$params[1]);

$select->where( "($table1Name.column2 = ?) OR ($table2Name.column2 = ?)", $params[2]);

//more preexisting code below.
return $select
}
```

Obviously, if I tried this as is, the program will happily return results that include a combination of, say, an entry where param1 is in table1.column1 and param2 is in table2.column2.

Comment: ZF1 reached its [EOL](https://framework.zend.com/blog/2016-06-28-zf1-eol.html) nearly 3 years ago. Is your ZF1-MVC-App openly accessible through the Internet? If so, it would be quite a safety hazard to keep it up.

Comment: Yes, it's accessible through the internet. Yes, I'm aware it's a safety hazard. Yes, management is aware of the risks and accepted it. At this point, I'm just doing what I can while waiting for the whole thing to blow up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I received some feedback from a friend and posting here for posterity.

They noticed my code already contains parentheses and recommended that I simply take advantage of orWhere() then write it like this:

```
$select->where("($tableName1.column1 = ?", $params[param1])
->where("$tableName1.column2 = ?)", $params[param2]);

$select->orWhere("($tableName1.column1 = ?",$params[param1])
->where("$tableName2.column2 = ?)",$params[param2]);
```